# What are some different ways of preparing flax seeds?

Tags: culinary-uses, seeds

I recently got to know the nutritious value of flax seeds.
What characteristics of these seeds should I know about and how can I incorporate them into my cooking?

Comment: Hi codaddict, welcome to Seasoned Advice!  I believe that flax seeds are probably an unusual enough ingredient to fit the [culinary uses guidelines](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/740/41), however, please keep in mind that questions on this site should relate to *cooking* or *preparing* food and not *consuming* it.  I've edited the question accordingly and hope that the edited question still retains the spirit of what you're asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky thing with flax seeds is to grind them fine enough. I've found that my coffee grinder, for example, won't do the job because the seeds have a very hard coat. You can buy vacuum packed pre-ground meal and that may be a good option.

Once you have ground flax seeds, they can be added in small amounts to baked goods very easily. Adding say 1/4 to 1/2 cup to a muffin, quickbread, or yeast bread will work nicely and add a nutty flavor.

They can also be sprinkled on salads or grain dishes. You could add a little sea salt and use them somewhat like [gomashio](http://www.herbivoracious.com/2010/03/gomashio-japanese-sesame-seed-salt-condiment-recipe.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can soak them in water overnight and incorporate them into bread, allowing for the added water, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I add two tablespoons of ground flax seeds to my morning yoghurt. Be sure to mix well!

Comment: Hi @no'am - could you provide some actual uses for ground flax seeds rather than just a recipe?

Comment: I think in this case the recipe was the use...

Answer (score 0):

Flax has various culinary uses:

1. as a substitute for fats in recipes
2. as a stand alone beverage; soaked in liquid overnight
3. as a 'digestive'; again soak seeds overnight in liquid
4. as a substitute for any other seed in recipes

enjoy!